# Calculus on Lamina

Tags: calculus, geometry

for a given lamina bounded by $x^2+y^2 ≤ a^2 , x ≥ 0 , y ≥ 0 $ find the centroid of this lamina. 
 I don't necessarily know how to start. I have tried finding the area of this circular sector, then divided by the moments of statics -- but, I do not know if that is right.

Comment: $$\bar{x}=\dfrac{\int x dm}{\int dm}$$

Comment: Would the limits for x be 0 to square root a ?

Comment: Is this the same for y ?

Comment: Actually I had made a typo. It should be $$dm=\dfrac{2\pi\rho x dx}{4}.$$ Note that centroid will lie on the line $y=x.$

Comment: So, then the centroid would be $ (\frac{2a}{3},\frac{2a}{3}) $ ?

Comment: I don't have good intuition on this problem

Comment: I did not calculate the centroid. If you can sketch the given region and $dm$ , you will get the idea.